# OutOfMemoryException in byte array for BitmapSource

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, bitmap

I've changed this question quite a bit as i now believe more context would make sense

I'm trying to create a new bitmap with another dpi from an already existing image.

However i get a OutOfMemoryException on large images, when it is trying to create a byte array like so

```
Private Function ConvertBitmapToXDPI(bitmapImage As BitmapImage, newDpi As Integer) As BitmapSource
     Dim width As Integer = bitmapImage.PixelWidth
     Dim height As Integer = bitmapImage.PixelHeight 'value is => 3456

     Dim stride As Integer = width * bitmapImage.Format.BitsPerPixel 'value is => 110592
     Dim pixelData As Byte() = New Byte(stride * height - 1) {} ' <- EXCEPTION!
     bitmapImage.CopyPixels(pixelData, stride, 0)

     Return BitmapSource.Create(width, height, newDpi, newDpi, bitmapImage.Format, Nothing, pixelData, stride)
 End Function
```

The method is used as a converter to change the DPI of images. However it throws a OutOfMemoryException on the marked line.

My question is if there's another way to do what I'm trying to? The above works fine for smaller images, but as soon as the image is of a larger size, this happens

Comment: What language and environment?

Comment: originally vb.net but wrote here in c# as that is what most are familiar with, and shouldn't be a problem to rewrite a potential answer in vb.net from c#

Comment: that was an answer to "what language".  How about an answer to "environment?"

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, but its on Windows

Comment: What are the values of `stride` and `height` when the exception occurs?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I've updated the question with the values